# how to find unmodified files linux with in a single directory

Tags: linux, find

I have a directory structure like this

```
# Server A
Dir_A : file, file2, file3, file4, file5
Dir_A/Dir_AA : file_aa1, file_aa2, file_aa3,file_aa4 
Dir_A/Dir_AB: file_ab1,file_ab2

Server B ? likewise
```

so i just want the unmodified files from only Dir_A not from internal directories of Dir_A i use below command  i am getting the files from the Dir_A/Dir_AA and Dir_A/Dir_AB as well.. what could be the exact command.

```
# find . -type f -mmin +3600
```

Thanks
Jagan

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-maxdepth` option with `find`

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -mmin +3600
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the "-maxdepth" option. From the `find` manpage:

-maxdepth levels
          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of direc-
          tories below the command line arguments.   '-maxdepth  0'  means
          only  apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.

Try the following:

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +3600

Comment: I have another question in my server daily 4 files created with extension date through cron job.. so every day we are checking whether they are created or not..how to check if they are created or not using script..